# Why Can't Push My New ViewController?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, xcode4.4

So, I have a main menu, and when I click one button from the main menu, I want to display another ViewController, so I create a NavigationController, I add the ViewController to this NavigationController and try to display, but nothing happens.
My code to push my new ViewController:

```
SubMenuViewController *subVC = [[SubMenuViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SubMenuViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[nav pushViewController:subVC animated:YES];
nav = nil;
```

This code is called in the MainViewController, when one button is pressed...

My SubMenuViewController creates a SplitViewController, with also two NavigationController, one for the table of the left, and the other for the table of the right, but these can't be the problem, right? 
If you need more information to help me, please, tell me

Comment: I could not do that because i did not have enough reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UINavigationController` that you are creating needs to be part of your view controller hierarchy.  As you have it, you've just created it but not added it to anything.  You'd probably be better served to create it at the top of your hierarchy and push sub-views onto it rather than trying to create it on the fly.

Comment: Thank you very much... So, my MainMenu is also a NavigationController, so I change [nav pushViewController:subVC animated:YES] to [self.navigationController pushViewController:subVC animated:YES];, but still, nothing happens...

Comment: Have you tried to debug or NSLog the value of subVC? Is it nil (perhaps because it failed to load)?

Comment: You might log the value of `self.navigationController` while you're at it.

Comment: When I print subVC, this prints 2012-09-03 19:59:23.314 MainApp[2877:fb03] <SubMenuViewController: 0x6db6000>... When I show this ViewController using presentModalViewController, it works, but I need to do this using pushViewController...

Comment: When I print using self.navigationController, prints (null), but when I create the NavigationController on the fly, it prints <UINavigationController>, but nothing happens...

Comment: What object is `self`?  If that's your MainMenu controller, it *is* your navigation controller, so you should be able to [self pushViewController:subVC].

Comment: When I print self, it prints <MainViewController>, when I print self.navigationController, it prints <null>

Comment: do you think that if I upload my project, you can give a look?

Answer (score 0):

I already kind of solved, even thought now can't go back, but can push one new ViewController. In the AppDelegate, I forgot to put this:

```
self.window.rootViewController = nab;
```

Now it push another ViewController. Thanks for the help highlycaffeinated